# What changes were made for Homeworld 1 & 2 Remastered?

Tags: version-differences, homeworld, homeworld-remastered-collection, homeworld-2

What changes were made for Homeworld & Homeworld 2 remastered when compared to the original releases?

Specifically, have there been any gameplay changes? The changes to the user interface and graphics are easy to see.

Comment: essentially HW1 seems to have been redone with HW2 style mechanics, and some of the textures / models have been replaced with models from HW2. Aside from that it seems like a very faithful remake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that you don't have to pick up all the resources at the end of a level (if you wanted to max resources that is) in HW1 anymore as they are auto-collected. Great time saver imo.